# What is the use of bishops?

Tags: crusader-kings

When I don't have bishops appointed the only difference I notice is that from time to time the Vatican proposes to fill in this position. What are they good for? And what qualifications must a courtier have to fill the position? When I have the choice between several candidates how to choose one, do their stats have any effect at all?